# Bug in fontspec 2.9a or luaotfload (which one?) while use LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, bugs, luaotfload

LuaLaTeX does not find the CMU font.

> Package fontspec Error: The font "CMUSansSerif" cannot be found. \setmainfont

At the same time, XeLaTeX compiles normally.

I am using TeXLive2023 (Win 10). Package `fontspec 2.9a`.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\title{Bug?}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

1. Tried using MikTeX, same problem.
2. Previous v2.8a work fine.
3. The bug appears only when loading CMU by name. Other system
   fonts are loaded by name normally.

```bash
kpsewhich --expand-var '$OPENTYPEFONTS'

'.;{{}d:/Programs/LaTeX/TeXLive/2023/texmf-config,
d:/Programs/LaTeX/TeXLive/2023/texmf-var,
d:/Projects/LaTeX/MyPackage,
!!d:/Programs/LaTeX/TeXLive/texmf-local,
!!d:/Programs/LaTeX/TeXLive/2023/texmf-config,
!!d:/Programs/LaTeX/TeXLive/2023/texmf-var,
!!d:/Programs/LaTeX/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist}/fonts/{opentype,truetype}//;
C:/windows/fonts//;
C:/Users/Sergiy/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts////'
```

Comment: Lualatex also compiles normally, with fontspec 2.9a, and non-CM otf fonts.

Comment: Your code doesn't require anything to be typeset in sans-serif. If I add `\textsf{Hello World}` after `\maketitle`, my system (MacOS 14.3.1 "Sonoma", MacTeX2023, fontspec 2.9a) has no trouble finding `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf`.

Comment: The bug does not depend on whether there is a font select command. Well, if it's not confirmed on Win 10, I'll look for my own problem.

Comment: @rallg yes, with non-CM fonts compile normally. Seems, problem with CMU.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the problem was in the local settings of TeXLive, the error would not show up in MikTeX. I installed MikTeX and the compilation also failed. And I always use the portable versions of the distributions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've got the logs here https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues/502

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is only solved by rolling back to older versions of packages.

Comment: which shows " File not found: "lmroman12-regular".)` so seems all files fail, not just CMU Serif?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, but there's also the MikTeX's log. And I don't see that in there.